# Filter a matrix by column name using column from another data set or list

Tags: r

I have a matrix like this:

```
df1

ABC    DEF      GHI      JKL
1       2        8        2
3       8        9        5
3       2        1        9
```

Then another df that has a column

```
df2

ID

ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Can I filter the matrix based on column name so only those that are in the ID column are kept? I tried:

```
list<-as_list(df2$ID)

df3<-df1[colnames(df1)%in% list,]
```

I want to get

```
ABC    DEF      GHI      
1       2        8        
3       8        9        
3       2        1
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do your selection

```
df1[, intersect(colnames(df1), as.character(df2$ID)]
```

Or using your approach

```
df1[, colnames(df1) %in%  as.character(df2$ID)]
```

I used `as.character(df2$ID)` to coerce `df2$ID` (if they were factor) to be character for correct matching

Answer (score 0):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    select(any_of(df2$ID))
```